# I am using a function to get the rotation of an object, but its failing in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, rotation

I am using this function:

```
// function that grabs the elements rotation in all browsers
function getRotationDegrees(obj) {
var matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
obj.css("-moz-transform")    ||
obj.css("-ms-transform")     ||
obj.css("-o-transform")      ||
obj.css("transform");
if(matrix !== 'none') {
    var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
    var a = values[0];
    var b = values[1];
    var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));
} else { var angle = 0; }
    return (angle < 0) ? angle +=360 : angle;
}
```

Which works beautifully in any other browser, but in IE8 it throws this error "Unable to get value of the property 'split': object is null or undefined". This is because the matrix variable is coming back as "undefined", but I need it to come back with the value of rotation which I am not sure how to get in IE8, any ideas?

Comment: IE8 has no CSS3 transform ?

Comment: IE8 rotations are implemented using filter. Are you certain you want to get into that?

Comment: on IE8 you can use only the css matrix filter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I mean I have to somehow and I would rather not re-write everything I have already done. This was a last minute request from the client to get this working in IE8.....So is there anyway for this function to get the right value out of a matrix filter?

Answer (score 1):

Untested solution, based on code i used to set the rotation of an element in IE8:

```
var matrix = obj.style.filter; // obj is a HTML Element. If you have jQuery, i suppose you could use that to get the filter property

// at this point matrix is a string like this:
    'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(' +
      'M11=' + cos + ', ' +
      'M12=' + (-sin) + ', ' +
      'M21=' + sin + ', ' +
      'M22=' + cos + ', ' +
      'sizingMethod="auto expand")';
// where cos and sin are Math.cos(angleInRadians) and Math.sin(angleInRadians)
```

The next step is to get one of those values (parsing the string i suppose) and use `Math.asin` or `Math.acos` to get the angle in radians. If you need it in degrees, you need to multiply it by 180 and divide by `Math.PI`

Similar to your code, you could do:

```
var values = matrix.match(/=.*?M/g);
var sin = values[2].substring(1,values[2].length-1);
var cos = values[0].substring(1,values[2].length-1);
```

to extract the sin and cos from the matrix.

Comment: I think this may work, a similar follow up question: To actually rotate something I am using this: 

`el.css({
                transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
            });`

Where "now" is the angle (I think)

How would i do that in IE8?

Comment: Just reverse what you did to extract the sin or cos. Turn the angle to radians, compute sin and cos and write the string i mentioned in the answer to the style.filter property of the element. If it doesn't work with jQuery, it will surely work with plain js.